# Need help remembering the name of an adventure (Shadowrun)

Tags: published-adventures, product-identification, shadowrun, shadowrun-sr3

I played and later GMed this adventure sometime between 2000 to 2003 and we were playing a hybrid of Shadowrun 2 and Shadowrun 3 (not all the 3rd ed books were out yet).

The adventure focused around a simsense star (or similar celebrity) the players have to protect.

I think in the start the players had to fake a kidnapping (for publicity) and someone else actually tries a real kidnapping at the same time (can't remember if this was real or added by the GM).

Later in the adventure she is kidnapped by an insect shaman(?) and was/is to be used as a host for an insect spirit queen. The players are kitted up by the megacorp who wanted the star back and they enter and fight their way through the hive. The megacorp bugged all the gear the players borrows with simsense recording gear and in the epilogue the star dies and the megacorp turns the player's hive fight into a simsense film.

Answer (score 9):

Wouldn't you know it. A bit more searching was all I needed. The adventure was called "Queen Euphoria". Reference: https://gurth.home.xs4all.nl/shadowrun/adventure%20dates.html

Comment: One of my favorites.